# Android widget listview animation gone after using setOnClickFillInIntent()

Tags: android, listview, animation, widget

I have a widget that shows a listview. When clicking on one of the items in the listview a default animation is shown as feedback to my touch.

After adding a clickHandler to the items (see code below), the animation is not shown anymore. How to get the (default) animation back?

```
    // Pseudo-Code: After setting setOnClickFillInIntent() the animation is gone
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),R.layout.simple_list_item_layout);
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.textView, fillInIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `R.id.textView` **is the root element** in `R.layout.simple_list_item_layout`.